# Is there a way to speed up my SMB file transfer of large files (>10 gb)?

Tags: wireless-networking, download, smb

I'm trying to carry out a file transfer from a genomics core of >10 gb data. I have to access the data through a VPN and then use SMB file transfer to transfer the data from the genomics core to my home laptop, but the speeds are painfully slow (>16 hours). Is there anyway to speed this up? Is this bottlenecked by my VPN connection?

Currently, I'm just copying the files over with the GUI. Should I do this using 'curl' or 'wget'?

Specs of my laptop:

Processor: 2.7 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
Memory: 8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
MacOS: Catalina 10.15.3

Specs of VPN connection based on Ookla speedtest (or is there something else I should use):

Ping: 37
Download Speed: 5.37 Mbps
Upload Speed: 5.29 Mbps

Comment: What does your IT Administrator have to say about the performance, because it has absolutely nothing to do with using SMB, because I am absolutely able to get  acceptable speed and transfer GBs worth of data in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to move over 10GB of data through a 5Mbps connection will be slow in general. I do not believe your laptop will come close to being a bottleneck in this situation. to verify this, you can use your Profiler and look at the ethernet traffic (bandwidth) and will likely see you are maxing out your connection. Getting with your internet provider and increasing the connection bandwidth will greatly help.

You are correct in thinking that wget or rsync would be a bit faster as they do not have the overhead SMB does, but will still be pretty slow on a 5Mbps connection. If you can increase the connection speed and use wget or rsync over SMB, you would have much better performance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ahh okay, that's super helpful. Thank you!!